# how to make a hierarchy table flat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Child | Parent
AA    |A
A     |X
B     |X
X     |Y
Y     |Z
```

The maxim dept is know, but at each branch the depth is unknown

I want it to pivot to something like this:

```
Lv1 | Lv2 | Lv3 |lv4 | lv5 
Z   |Y    |X    |B   |Null
Z   |Y    |X    |A   |AA
```

Can some one pls help, if can provide the SQL plus some explain, highly appreciate!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The solution will perhaps be product specific.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: and what is The maxim dept ? 5 ?

Comment: not sure how shall I format my SQL code to be a more visible way. but above is the code I copied from a search result, it worked except that it is from bottom to up, but what I need is be aligned from up to bottom.

Comment: Do not post code or additional information in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer at this link: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1071035-392-1.aspx

and here is my altered code:

```
with cteTree
as
(

   Select CID,PID,
          CNAME as LV1,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV2,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV3,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV4,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV5,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV6,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV7,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV8,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV9,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV10,
          cast(Null as nvarchar(100)) as LV11,

          0  as Level
     from PSFT_DEPT_TREE
    where PID = 0
    union all
   Select Child.CID,
          Child.PID,
          LV1,
          case when Level+1 = 1 then CNAME else LV2 end,
          case when Level+1 = 2 then CNAME else LV3 end,
          case when Level+1 = 3 then CNAME else LV4 end,
          case when Level+1 = 4 then CNAME else LV5 end,
          case when Level+1 = 5 then CNAME else LV6 end,
          case when Level+1 = 6 then CNAME else LV7 end,
          case when Level+1 = 7 then CNAME else LV8 end,
          case when Level+1 = 8 then CNAME else LV9 end,
          case when Level+1 = 9 then CNAME else LV10 end,
          case when Level+1 = 10 then CNAME else LV11 end,

          Level+1
     from CteTree
     join PSFT_DEPT_TREE child
      on  child.PID = CteTree.CID
)

select * from cteTree
```